# change default url in mvc 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, url, xslt

In MVC 4, I created an application named “PhotoGallery” I run it from visual studio as below:
http://localhost:55971/

And when it is deployed on Dev server it gets the URL as below:

http://devServer/PhotoGallery

Is it possible if I can run visual studio project like in Dev server? So my path could be as below?

http://localhost:55971/PhotoGallery

Issue is that some of the references which works on visual studio need to change on Dev server to work by adding dev application folder (IIS Folder) name in front.

E.g. I have XSLT which create download links as below. And on Dev server I need to add “PhotoGallery” in dynamic hyperlink generation.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Contents/Downloads/download">
                          <li>
                            <a href="PhotoGallery/Download?FileName={@file}&amp;App={@App}"  class="fa {@icon}">
                              <xsl:apply-templates/>
                              <xsl:value-of select="@link"></xsl:value-of>
                            </a>
                          </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, open the properties of the web project, go to web tab and set it in **Project URL**:

[image]

Comment: cool. How I can make it dynamic. e.g. <a href="/">Home</a> to home page I can use <a href="/PhotoGallery">Home</a>. But if I change IIS_Folder name e.g. to PictureGallery I need to change everywhere. Is there any way without hard coding? e.g. with <a href="/">Home</a> I shoud get to http://localhost:55971/PhotoGallery or http://localhost:55971/PictureGallery?